# Transcoding Satellite online TV Channels to Internet Via Help of Cloud?

Tags: video, streaming, encoding, transcoding, capturing

Is it possible for me to transcode nearly 25 live tv channels that run on satellite to internet. Is it possible for me to that via help of Cloud media services from most known cloud providers. As i know, i need some capturing hardware to capture satellite tv channels. Can i rent that in cloud. Can you guide me on anyhow to starting point?

Regards.

Comment: It is definitely possible, however there are so many ways to do it your question isn't specific enough to answer. If you don't yet know how to transcode a channel to another form, you might be better asking a question asking about the technical process required there. The parts of your question about renting in the cloud, and the fact there is a major legal problem you will face are also reasons I'm voting to close this question.

Comment: Hey Mahhem, i am new to this transcoding field, thats why i am asking to guide on starting point about this issue. I dont know how the transcoding process through capture cards does. I dont know what program and what capture card should i use. There are a lot of garbage and out of date information on the internet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it isn't possible to do it through the cloud in the way you have described.  It is possible to offload transcoding to the cloud (changing from one file format or size to another) however you can't use that cloud for capture hardware as that needs to be physically connected to the source.  There are no services that I know of that will run a satellite box for you and hook it up to capture for you, so the source would have to be at your satellite box.

Also, while it is possible to have transcoding done online, to stream 25 uncompressed satellite channels over the Internet to a cloud service provider for transcoding would require a MASSIVE amount of bandwidth to be available.  You really don't have any option other than local transcoding for that kind of thing in order to get the bandwidth requirement down far enough to have streaming 25 channels to become viable.

Even then, you would have a hard time streaming 25 channels in HD quality without a massive upstream Internet connection.  Even 25 SD streams would be require more than most common ISP connections would support.